# Activity displayed as one character only

Tags: sql

Good Morning

I created a little procedure where I add activities to a database table.
This is the code I used.

```
USE dbActivities
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE addActivity

@ActivityDate VARCHAR,
@description VARCHAR,
@maxPeople INT,
@Cost MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Activity(ActivityDate,Description, MaxPeople, Cost)
    VALUES(@ActivityDate, @description, @maxPeople, @Cost)
END
GO
```

I then select the table to view it.

```
USE dbActivities
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE viewActivities
AS
    SELECT * FROM Activity
GO
```

The strange thing however is that the Description is displayed as only one character in the datatable. So, if I added the description...say "Swimming", when I view the table it is only displayed with one character 'S'.

Why is that?

regards
Arian

Answer (score 4):

The `VARCHAR` equals to `VARCHAR(1)`. Use e.g. `VARCHAR(60)` instead.

Comment: FYI varchar by itself defaults to 30 in a CAST